# Why don't my grid columns layout correctly in Firefox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

so on this website http://kimandydev.com/
the spacing is weird on only the 4th row.

Everything is gridded out perfectly on Chrome and Safari, but on in Firefox.
I used Advanced Custom Fields to feed the content just FYI.

Can someone inspect it on firefox and somehow figure out what is causing it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, please include a [mcve] in your question per our rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some of your images aren't the same aspect ratio, and Firefox considers the partial-pixel height difference when it lays out the floats, so they don't clear.

Be sure that all your images are exactly 1000x1500.

You could also force image sizes at each breakpoint using media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 940px) { /* or whatever it is */
    .front-img {
        height: 330px;
    }
}
```